# Symfony 2.4 You have requested a non-existent service "payment.encryption_service"

Tags: php, service, symfony-2.4

I'm migrating a symfony project from 2.0 to 2.4 version.
I've correctly configured all the parameters and services.

But the problem occured with JMS vendor, this is the error shown:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException'
>   with message 'You have requested a non-existent service
>   "payment.encryption_service".' in
>   C:\wamp\www\symfony\app\bootstrap.php.cache on line 2027

This message is blocking me, do you have any issue, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I don't know exactly what happened, but my problems went away after I manually cleared the cache using

```
rm -rf app/cache/prod/*
```

Considering your settings are on Windows, try manually deleting entries at app\cache\prod using Windows Explorer. I couldn't use `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` since the console would crash after showing that error message.

Answer (score 1):

Another correct answer could be checking every `service.yml` in yml parser, for example http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com

```
You have requested a non-existent service
```

could mean, that symfony can't parse correctly `.yml` files.

Answer (score 0):

This means your the mentioned parameter is missing from your app/config/parameters.yml or other alike file that you are using to store your parameters. Set this parameter to a value and it should work.

E.G. I had the same error being `"You have requested a non-existent parameter "domain".`

I then added following line to the parameters.yml file:

```
domain: example.com
```

That did the trick.